# Data member 'queryCallback' cannot be a member template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm having problems to compile the following member definition:

```
template<typename... A>
std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(A...)> > queryCallback;
```

Error is as stated in the title:

```
/databasedispatcher.h:14: error: data member 'queryCallback' cannot be a member template
```

I realize I can't use a template definition for a member that is not a method/function. Considering that, how can I use `<A...>` in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Define a template alias and make querycallback be a variable of a specific instance of that alias. Template variable will be part of C++14, but I don't know their limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an educated guess, you need to define it as template alias:

```
template<typename... A>
using queryCallback = std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(A...)>>;
```

**Code Example:**

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename... A>
using queryCallback = std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(A...)>>;

int main()
{
  auto foo = [](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << std::endl; };
  queryCallback<int, int> A("foo", foo);

  std::cout << std::get<0>(A) << std::endl;
  std::get<1>(A)(2, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> foo
>
> 2 + 2 = 4

Answer (score 0):

Use [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template<typename... B>
struct T
{
    template<typename... A> using QueryCallbackType = std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(A...)>>;
    QueryCallbackType<B...> query_callback;
};
```